# Return length of string for comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like, string-length

Is it possible to compare two strings on the length of the second string for example.

```
SELECT ProductDescription, Products  
FROM ProductDescription
INNER JOIN Products 
ON ProductDescription LIKE LEFT(Products, LENGTH(Products)) + '%'
```

Where Products is the string we are comparing with and the length of the comparison I would like to be the same length as the string if that makes sense?

Say we have Hydrogen and Hydrogen Oxide Like matches both so I need to specify what I am comparing...

further more the Description fields may for instance state:

> Hydrogen Oxide is water.
>   Oxygen is air. 
>   Hydrogen II and Oxygen II can be combined to create water. 
>   Hydrogen is a gas. 
>   Oxygen II is undefined.

I have a list of states for example:
Oxygen.
Hydrogen.
Oxygen II.
Hydrogen II.
Hydrogen Oxide.

I would like to append the Correct chemicals to the Descriptions they concern. for example:

> Hydrogen Oxide is water. | Hydrogen Oxide.
>   Oxygen is air. | Oxygen Hydrogen II and Oxygen II can be combined to
>   create water. | Hydrogen II, Oxygen II Hydrogen is a gas. | Hydrogen
>   Oxygen II is undefined. | Oxygen II.

The results I can get from the query vary but I am trying to avoid:

> Hydrogen Oxide is water. | Hydrogen Oxide. Oxygen is air. | Oxygen.
>   Hydrogen II and Oxygen II can be combined to create water. | Oxygen II.
>   Hydrogen II and Oxygen II can be combined to create water. | Hydrogen.
>   II Hydrogen is a gas. | Hydrogen Oxygen II is undefined. | Oxygen.

Comment: I do not understand you ;)

Comment: aha well I have multiple very similar strings that I am comparing and would like to specifically set the length of the string I am comparing from the left if possible, I seem to get the shortest match so I would like to specify length in the comparison.

Comment: How is LEFT(Products, LENGTH(Products)) not the same as Products?  Name where the column came from.  Avoid column names the same as the table.  Which DB?

Comment: the tables are not the same the code is just hypothetical as I cannot post the exact code ;) I have many Products which will match but it must match the full string else the query will return invalid strings due to the nature of the products. A basic example of products would be Hydrogen and Hydrogen Dioxide Like will match both...

Comment: Because the name is in the Description if it is a match I append it to the Description. The description is not an exact match of the product there is other data in the Description field.

Comment: Can you add a tag for what database you are using?

Comment: I've read this a few times and cannot make sense of the question. Please consider providing more details of the data in your hypothetical tables, fully qualifying the fields with tables names in your example, more clearly specifying what you want as an output, and as much as you can describe about the business request. Reading your question and comments as it is it's almost like you are wanting ProductDescription = Products, but this makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at this question the Answer to this question is actually very simple...
The Queries suggested by the guys here at Stack Overflow and the code I had written myself, in fact did exactly as it was supposed to... That being said the data sets were very messy causing some invalid results to be returned. This can only be corrected in one of two ways, one way being cleaning the data set through string manipulation. The other method to be obtain a clean data set of which you can compare implicitly with the clean data set obtained which is the method I had taken to bypass the issue of invalid data... I hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  I am thinking you want:

```
SELECT ProductDescription, Products  
FROM ProductDescription INNER JOIN
     Products 
    ON ProductDescription LIKE Products + '%' OR
       Products LIKE ProductDescription + '%';
```

This is one way of accomplishing this.  Note that the use of `LIKE` with wildcards will pretty much kill the performance of the query.

Comment: If the database is Oracle, **trailing** wildcards will not prevent use of an index.

Comment: This is a good result not quite the exact answer I'm looking for as I have had a result with for example: Oxygen and Oxygen II